# From CS50 lecture 2 / strln : the link between printf and for

Tags: c, cs50

**I can't understand why the code 'printf("After: ") prints something here. For example, before: hi \n After: HI, even though after "After" is a blank.**

```
string s = get_string("Before: ");
printf("After: ");

for (int i=0, n = strlen(s); i < n; i++)
{
    if (s[i] >= 'a' && s[i] <= 'z')
    {
        printf("%c", s[i] - 32);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%c", s[i]);
    }
}
printf("\n");
```

Comment: There are lines of code after `printf("After: ")` which contain more `printf` calls which produce the rest of the output.

Comment: `printf` does not implicitly output a newline at the end of its text, so a line of text can be produced from multiple `printf` calls.

Comment: Did you run your code in a debugger and step through the instructions? You really should do that.